# How to force old versions of eog to run in a new instance?

Tags: python, image, popen, sh

I have a little python script where I display images by writing them to a temp file, calling eog on the temp file, and then calling rm on the temp file after the eog process closes. The relevant code looks basically like this:

```
os.popen('(eog --new-instance tmp.jpg; rm tmp.jpg)&')
```

The --new-instance flag is important; without that, if there is already an eog process, the eog call simply tells the pre-existing eog process to display tmp.jpg and returns right away. rm executes before the pre-existing eog process can open tmp.jpg. The pre-existing eog process then crashes.

Unfortunately, I don't have complete control over some of the systems I use this script on. Some of them have an outdated version of eog installed which does not support --new-instance, and I don't want to burn up my quota space building a local copy.

Is there some way I can launch eog in a way that prevents it from detecting if there are other instances? Or is there another reliable strategy for displaying images in a sophisticated viewer (ie, supports zooming, panning, etc.) that won't clutter up my directory with temp files?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this overall, but if you would like to make sure `rm` doesn't run before `eog` is finished, you can use `wait()` on a `Popen` object.  This will solve your crashing issues, but you'll also need to check if an existing `eog` process is running.

```
import subprocess as subp
import os, signal
findInstance = subp.check_output('ps -eaf | grep eog', shell=True).strip()
for line in findInstance.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
    if line.split()[7] == 'eog':
        os.kill(int(line.split()[1]), signal.SIGKILL)
subp.Popen(['eog','tmp.jpg']).wait()
subp.Popen(['rm','tmp.jpg'])
```

This looks for the `eog` process, and if it finds it, kills it.  Then, it respawns `eog`, which can display the new image, and waits for `eog` to finish before it removes the temporary image.

Answer (score 0):

`eog` monitors files by name so you can't just open an image and then safely unlink it.

You could introduce a delay before deleting the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import time

from threading import Thread

def write_image_to(f):
    f.write(open(os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures/lenaNN.jpg'), 'rb').read())

def f(write_image_to, delay=None):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fileobj:
        write_image_to(fileobj)
        fileobj.flush() # ensure writing to disk

        r = subprocess.call(['eog','--new-instance',fileobj.name],close_fds=True)
        if r: # eog don't support new-instance
           subprocess.call(['eog', fileobj.name], close_fds=True)
           if delay:
              time.sleep(delay)

for _ in xrange(10): 
    Thread(target=f, args=(write_image_to, 3600)).start()
```

To avoid waiting for the delay to expire you can invoke the script in the background:

```
$ python your_script.py & disown
```

`disown` make sure that the script continues to work after you logout.